Optimal threshold for a predictive covariate on treatment effect
here  a physician with a moderate understanding of statistics and am seeking guidance on analyzing a continuous covariate (biomarker) that I suspect is predictive of treatment effect. My analysis involves time-to-event data, and I plan to model it as follows (transformations aside):
Y = a0 + treatment + CV + treatment * CV
Here, CV represents the covariate, and the focus is on the interaction term (treatment * CV). My primary goal is to identify the value of the covariate that maximizes the difference in treatment response.
For prognostic covariates, I have previously worked with a statistician to achieve a similar goal by employing non-linear fitting with restricted cubic splines. We visually identified the point where the lower bound of the 95% confidence interval exceeded the null value. For survival data, we used Maximally Selected Rank Statistics to get asignificant threshold.
Could you provide guidance or recommend a suitable approach for the predictive covariate? Thanks!

On the one hand, the approach using splines makes sense. On the other hand, I sincerely hope you won't be calculating any p values after that model selection step, because those would be invalid. I would recommend you go and talk to your statistician again, unless you feel comfortable re-doing that earlier analysis on your own.

To meet the original goal you must use simultaneous and not pointwise confidence intervals.  But I think this approach is not to be reocommended.  A threshold is only useful if the relationship is flat on either side of the threshold.  Use the spline fit and its confidence band as the end result.

Thank all for the comments! Actually I for the previous work, I fit on my own the splines following Harrell's (amazing) regression modelling strategies book and reading tons of literature (plus the R-package RCSplot). It was for a prognostic model (non treated patients, but another clinical setting). The question here, having treated/untreated patients (and here is where I am slightly lost), should I fit the spline on the interaction? If I fit it on the covariate I would be modelling (as far as I understand) the covariates prognostic effect not the predictive value. Many thanks again!

A regression model by itself isn't going to document that your continuous covariate is a reliable predictive biomarker. As this review states:

A predictive biomarker is defined by the finding that the presence or change in the biomarker predicts an individual or group of individuals more likely to experience a favorable or unfavorable effect from the exposure to a medical product or environmental agent. Proving that a biomarker is useful for this purpose requires a rigorous approach to clinical studies. Ideally, patients with or without the biomarker are randomized to one of two or more treatments (or a placebo comparator) and differences in outcome as function of treatment are significantly related to the difference in presence, absence, or level of the biomarker. Proof of a reliable predictive biomarker thus represents a “high hurdle” to clear.

We can, however, determine whether the association between outcome and treatment differs as a function of the level of the continuous covariate (CV). That's addressed by examining the coefficients associated with the treatment:CV interaction in the model.
Fitting CV with a spline is certainly a good choice. If you use Frank Harrell's rms package, the model in your nomenclature might take the general form
Y ~ a0 + Tx + rcs(CV, 4) + rcs(CV, 4):Tx + other terms ...

allowing 4 knots for CV in both its individual fit and its interaction with Tx. It's important to include other outcome-associated predictors, to avoid omitted-variable bias. There's also a risk that your CV is just a proxy for other well known, routinely documented outcome predictors. Including those other predictors helps evaluate that.
The statistical significance of the multiple terms associated with the interaction is then conveniently evaluated with the rms package's anova() function applied to an object produced via the package. That performs a "chunk test" evaluating all the interaction terms together.
As Frank Harrell says in a comment, however, looking for a cutoff in CV "is not to be recommended." Section 2.4.1 of his Regression Modeling Strategies (RMS) explains in detail, with many references, why looking for a cutoff this way is a bad idea. As he continued in the comment: "Use the spline fit and its confidence band as the end result."
Plotting results from the Predict() function in the rms package can document associations of interest. A reviewer might want to see outcome versus continuous CV plotted separately on the same graph for control and Tx, evaluated at typical values of the other predictors in the model. That documents how much CV is associated with outcome directly and how its association with outcome differs with Tx. That's an important complement to a plot of the difference between control and Tx as a continuous function of CV, which will probably document the futility of trying to find a specific CV cutoff.
The above assumes that you have enough data to support such a complex model. If not, consult Chapter 4 of RMS for ways to design the model to minimize the chance of overfitting, by reducing the number of effective predictors without using the outcomes.
Finally, note that the above model form would not document whether the association of CV with outcome, including its interaction with Tx, also depends on other predictors. That would require further interaction terms and a model that might push up against overfitting limits. That's why the most reliable documentation of a predictive biomarker is done via a randomized trial in which values of those other predictors are (ideally) balanced between groups.
